# Website with tutorial-style help

Tags: help

I am developing a website for a client and since it's quite complicated for new users I suggested creating a simple tutorial during the first visit. The background is supposed to darken a bit, one of the elements stays lightened up and some note appears next to it. When user clicks OK it goes to the next element and so on. Now the problem is he wants to see a live example before making decision. I remember i saw this feature on multiple sites. I can't remember any of them. Could anyone drop some links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called user onboarding and there are many examples:

https://zapier.com/blog/user-onboarding-user-interface-inspiration/

http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/ux-flows-onboarding

http://blog.invisionapp.com/an_intro_to_user_onboarding_part_1/

https://uk.pinterest.com/marcuscoghlan/ui-patterns-onboarding/